# Android In App notification display using FireBase

Tags: android, push-notification

Hopefully I am phrasing this correctly, but does Android provide a standard mechanism (such as a popup or banner) to display notifications when inside the application? The notifications will be sent to the device via FireBase, once I receive the Notification in the FireBase service onMessageReceived() I want to then  display the notification inside the App, so the user can then either let the notice disappear or can react to it (bringing them somewhere else in the application).

So in the Firebase messaging service I want to react to the notification based on the data passed in (I know this will only work with the App in the foreground, but I have implemented other code to handle it in the Intent from the system tray):

```
public class MyCompanyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            // Do a popup or something to alert the user and then allow them to move to that activity

    }
}
```

Is there a pattern or standard way to do this in Android or is this something I need to code myself? I can't seem to find any reference to it in the Android documentation.

Also, how would this relate to Notification Channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to an example here: https://demonuts.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/

Follow the method `private void generateNotification(String messageBody)` in the post.

Starting from Android O and onwards, it is necessary to post the notification in a notification channel. A notification channel helps to group the notification that our app sends.

So in the above post where u create the notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder` just call method `setChannel()` and set the created channel. Highlevel steps would be-

1. Create Notification channel:

   ```
   NotificationManager notificationManager =
   (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   String channelId = "some_channel_id";
   CharSequence channelName = "Some Channel";
   int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

   NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new 
   NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
   notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
   notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
   notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
   notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 
   400, 300, 200, 400});

   notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
   ```
2. Create Notification and set channel

   ```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = 
   (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   int notifyId = 1;
   String channelId = "some_channel_id";

   Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
       .setContentTitle("Some Message")
       .setContentText("You've received new messages!")
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
       .setChannel(channelId)
       .build();

   notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
   ```

Additionally for a detailed description on notification channel follow https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c

Comment: Thanks. I implemented something similar but I found that while I received the notification inside my application, the click_action seemed to be disabled (I need to perform an action when clicked). Was I doing something wrong, or is that the expected behavior?

Comment: So if you want to add some action on Notification, you need to add a pending intent  to your notification. I guess the method is ```setIntent(<PendingAction>)```.